# Unable to view local PDF file in Ionic App (using ng2-pdf-viewer)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3

I'm trying to view pdf file in ionic app using ng2-pdf-viewer npm package.

Its working fine on the browser using a command `ionic serve`

It is also working alright while running on a device in debug mode with a command `ionic cordova run android -l -c --debug`

But when I create an android build using `ionic cordova build android`, and then try to view pdf files. It gives the following error

> UnknowErrorException: Failed to fetch

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

First you need to convert pdf file to Base64 string

You can do this by using ionic native [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/file/) plugin

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';


pdflink:any;
constructor( private file: File){
    this.fileToBase64("myFile.pdf", "file:///data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/files")
    }
```

Convert PDF file to Base64 string

```
async  fileToBase64(filename, filepath){
            let base64String =  await this.file.readAsDataURL(filepath, filename);
            this.pdfurl=base64String.slice(28);
      this.Base64toArrayBuffer() 
            }
```

Convert Base64 string to ArrayBuffer

```
  Base64toArrayBuffer(){
        var binary_string = window.atob(this.pdfurl);
          var len = binary_string.length;
          var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
          }
         this.pdflink= bytes.buffer;
    }
```

HTML code

```
 <pdf-viewer [src]="pdflink" style="display: block;" render-text-mode="0" [render-text]="true" [page]="currentpage" [show-all]="false" (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"></pdf-viewer>
```